# How to compare known hours ad current hour in android?

Tags: android, time

i am trying to use a start hour and an end hour, and calculate the percents of the current time (which is between startHour and endHour).
For example, if the time is now 12:00 and startHour = 11:00 and End Hour = 14:00, it should return 33 (rounded), because 33% of the time has passed.

i have tried the following, but maybe i am mixing different formats... i don't know:

```
double currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
double startTime = Time.UTC(2012, 3, 20, 22, 0, 0);
double endTime = Time.UTC(2012, 3, 20, 23, 30, 0);
int prg = (int)((currentTime - startTime)/(endTime - startTime));
```

in this code i assume that the current hour is between 22:00 and 23:30

Thanks
Eyal

Comment: start and end hours are about 6.1E12, while current time is 1E13...

Comment: You should check whether startTime is bigger than currentTime. Anyway, print all the values you're calculating to learn why do you get a negative number.

Comment: As stated here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#UTC(int, int, int, int, int, int), the UTC method you're using is deprecated for a while now. You'll see the workaround inside the link.

Comment: It says to use Calendar.set(...) and it doesn't work for me... no set method in Calendar

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9113/discussion-between-egor-and-eyal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried my self and found *error while getting time in milliseconds for Current Time calendar* instance.

You were getting error because the **time in milisecond for CurrentTime was not accurate**, it was buggy somehow and **was representing time of 1 month less than current** so that's why you were getting answer in nagative.

You can perform this below way.

```
   Calendar calCurr = Calendar.getInstance();
    Log.i("Time in mili of Current - Normal", ""+calCurr.getTimeInMillis()); // see what it gives? dont know why?
    Date date = new Date();
    calCurr.set(date.getYear()+1900, date.getMonth()+1, date.getDate(), date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds());// so added one month to it
    Log.i("Time in mili of Current - after update", ""+calCurr.getTimeInMillis()); // now get correct

    Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
    start.set(2012, 12, 1, 11, 28, 0);

    Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
    end.set(2012, 12, 1, 13, 28, 0);

    if((start.compareTo(calCurr)==-1) && (calCurr.compareTo(end)==-1) && (start.compareTo(end)==-1))
    {

    double hrBetweenStartEnd = (end.getTimeInMillis()-start.getTimeInMillis())/3600000;
    double hrBetweenStartCurr = (calCurr.getTimeInMillis()-start.getTimeInMillis())/3600000;

    int percentage = (int) ((100*hrBetweenStartCurr)/hrBetweenStartEnd);
    Log.i("Percentage", ""+percentage);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't program android, but I am pretty sure that the problem is that months are zero-based (January = 0), that is, 3 is not March but April.

That is `Time.UTC(2012, 3, 20, 22, 0, 0)` does not represent 22:00 of March 20th, but of April 20th. So the current time was about one month before that time.