# JAVA - Is it a bug in java.util.Calendar class or what?

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

I have faced the same problem many times.

The Same Problem was With This Question and Got Solution Like the Same,
[How to compare known hours ad current hour in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795464/how-to-compare-known-hours-ad-current-hour-in-android/9817945#9817945)

**Problem :**

When I use `Calendar calCurr = Calendar.getInstance();` to get the Calendar object of current date and time, It always return me wrong.

I have put logs and checked it and to make it correct I had to add in years and months and then I got the correct object for Current Date and Time.

**See My Example :**

```
    Calendar calCurr = Calendar.getInstance();
    Log.i("Time in mili of Current - Normal", ""+calCurr.getTimeInMillis()); 
                // see what it gives? dont know why?

    Date date = new Date();
    calCurr.set(date.getYear()+1900, date.getMonth()+1, date.getDate(), date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds());
                // so added one month to it

    Log.i("Time in mili of Current - after update", ""+calCurr.getTimeInMillis()); 
                // now get correct
```

**Question :**

- Why it's giving the wrong output?
- Is it a bug in there or My concept about the Calendar class is wrong?
- tell me what should have been done
  for that?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger the Question link given above is the same problem of mine..

Comment: why it not give both calendar equal when one is current object and anothe with values set of current date and from db..

Comment: because they are not equal: the first is current time, the second is one month (`month + 1`) ahead of current time - you are adding ONE to the month! Also print `calCurr.getTime().toString()` each time to see the difference

Comment: added a reply to the question link: the author is using `3` as the month, but the month is zero-based, that is `3` represents April not March (when the question was posted)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works perfectly as expected if you change to `getDate()` it outputs :

> Time in mili of Current - Normal Wed Apr 04 11:34:34 BST 2012
>
> Time in mili of Current - after update Fri May 04 11:34:34 BST 2012

What do you expect ? And in milleseconds it also equals 30 days :

> Time in mili of Current - Normal 1333535834557
>
> Time in mili of Current - after update 1336127834557

and the calculation is (difference, divided by milliseconds in a day) :

```
1336127834557 - 1333535834557 = 2 592 000 000

2592000000 / 86400000 = 30
```

And todays date in milliseconds after 1970 is [1333536754](http://www.esqsoft.com/javascript_examples/date-to-epoch.htm) ... which fits, I don't see a problem.

**EDIT**

**Your Problem is you are setting Month like 3 for march...there you need to set 2..cause months are indexed from 0 to 11.**

Comment: You might not seen that...the correct miliseconds according the current date and time is the second one..not the normal one.

Comment: What, no it isn't. You output current datetime, then change it and out put that. I just ran the code. It returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT

Comment: It gives the correct time in millseconds ! http://www.esqsoft.com/javascript_examples/date-to-epoch.htm What millisecond value are you expecting for todays date ?

Comment: I don't understand what you want. What millisecond value do you expect and why ?

Comment: cause taking the normal object..if get to compare with equals method it doesnt return true even if they are same..after the Update..only it return true..so...see this SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795464/how-to-compare-known-hours-ad-current-hour-in-android/

Comment: posted in that link..with answer..please check

Comment: just use joda-time, it will become the new standard

Comment: I have no issue using anything else..infact using that already..so that's why I set title "Is it a bug in java.util.Calendar class or what?".. I want answer for that..

Comment: No its not a bug. I still fail to see the problem you are having. What millisecond value do you expect for todays date ?

Comment: why it not give both calendar equal when one is current object and anothe with values set of current date and from db..

Comment: because they are different times

Comment: means..if i take calendar.getInstance and set another cal.set(values of current manually)..then they are diff?

Answer (score 5):

Do not use `date.getXXX()`. Do not use any setter or getter except `Date.getTime()`. They are all deprecated. Using them would cause unexpected results.

If you call `Calendar.getInstance()`, it is already set to the current date. If you want to set or add days, months, whatever, set them on the calendar.

E.g. `calCurr.set(Calendar.MONTH,2)` or `calCurr.add(Calendar.DAY,1)`.

Comment: please just see ..I have used only getTimeInMillis() when it didnt gave me correct I just tried to find correct.

Comment: You used `calCurr.set(date.getYear()+1900, date.getMonth()+1, date.getDate(), date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds());` which is the wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

> Calendar months are zero-indexed. So when want to set for March its 2 not 3

Also, Don't set year, month and date from the Date object.  If you must initialise a Calendar to a date, do it like this:

```
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal.setTime(date);
```

be aware that your Date object might be a different locale to what you think it is.

Comment: I want to know about getTimeInMillis() and its output.

Comment: That's the real catch...You good...Thank you So much.I want to accept this answer too..

Answer (score 2):

It is NOT a bug, the Calendar is returning what it should (at least here it is).

```
Calendar calCurr = Calendar.getInstance();
Log.i("Time in mili of Current - Normal", ""+calCurr.getTimeInMillis()); 
            // see what it gives? dont know why?
```

I got 1333546375707 milliseconds, which is the correct value (also calculated by hand).
Which value are you expecting here? How you know it is wrong?

---

```
Date date = new Date();
calCurr.set(date.getYear()+1900, date.getMonth()+1, date.getDate(), date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds());
            // so added one month to it
```

Why adding ONE to the month? Month of both Date and Calendar are zero-based - no need to add 1.

---

**EDIT**
Calculating by hand (approximated):

```
2012  - 42 years * 365.24 days/year * 86400 seconds/day
April - (31 + 29 + 31) days * 86400
4th   - 3 days * 86400
13:30 - 13.5 hours * 3600 seconds/hour
        ====================
        1333553112 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

When Calendar object is created by using Calendar.getInstance() the instance variable "time" in the Calendar object is set and this value will get changed only if you use 
Calendar.setTimeInMillis() function.
Code snippet from Calendar object:

```
public long getTimeInMillis() {
        if (!isTimeSet) {
        updateTime();
    }
        return time;
    }
```

Here "isTimeSet" will become "true" when Calendar.getInstance() is called and it returns "time" every time without updating the time.

This is the reason you get the same value of time every time you call 
calCurr.getTimeInMillis();

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's the weird implementation of `Calendar`.
For some reasons January is month 0, and years are not very logical as well.

I recommend Joda time library.

Comment: Thanks..I want to know..why the Calendar not returning what it should be returning.

Comment: The calendar is returning precisely what it should be returning given its input data.  You are feeding it incorrect data.  Date.getMonth() will _NOT_ give you the equivalent Month in a Calendar object.

Answer (score 0):

We are using below lines of code for finding current date and time It's working fine our side.

```
            java.util.Calendar calc = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();

        int day = calc.get(java.util.Calendar.DATE);
        int month = calc.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH)+1;
        int year = calc.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR);

        String dayStr,monthStr;
        if(day<10){
            dayStr = "0"+day;
        }else{
            dayStr = ""+day;
        }
        if(month<10){
            monthStr = "0"+month;
        }else{
            monthStr = ""+month;
        }
        /*String currentdate = monthStr+"/"+dayStr+"/"+year+" ";*/
        String currentdate = dayStr+"/"+monthStr+"/"+year+" ";

        /*String currenttime = currentdate + String.valueOf(calc.get(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))+ ":"+
        String.valueOf(calc.get(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE))+":"+String.valueOf(calc.get(java.util.Calendar.SECOND));*/

        return currentdate;
```

Comment: Mayur thanks for the code..I dont want codes..I want explainations...Why at first time calCurr.getTimeInMillis() return the wrong.

Comment: @Frankenstein - how you got to that result?

Answer (score 0):

Java Date Based API  is not properly designed.
in future versions I think some problems of The API are planned to address.

I would recommend to use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).